# Dynamically scrape paginated table with BeautifulSoup and store results in csv?

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pagination

The code runs but the dataframe is empty.
In the URL below both the **YEAR** and the **PAGE** are dynamic.
I want to iterate through both and get the **table td** and (if possible) the dependend data under **acc. date** and extract the results in ***year.csv*** of each year.

```
import requests, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request

url = 'https://aviation-safety.net/wikibase/dblist.php?Year=1916&sorteer=datekey&page=1'
req = Request(url , headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36'})


with open('1916_aviation-safety.csv', "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["acc. date", "Type", "Registration","operator", "fat", "Location", " ", "dmg", " ", " "])

    while True:
        print(url)
        html = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

        # Go throught table = tbody and extract the data under the 'td' tag
        for row in soup.select('table > tbody > tr'):
            writer.writerow([c.text if c.text else '' for c in row.select('td')])
            print(row)

        # If more than one page then iterate through all of them        
        if soup.select_one('div.pagenumbers > span.current + div.a'):
            url = soup.select_one('div.pagenumbers > span.current + div.a')['href']
        else:
            break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some changes to your script which should make it easier to debug and to maintain. It uses pandas to make writing to CSV easier as well as concurrent.futures to speed things up. If you have questions let me know, basically each year is scraped concurrently, I scrape the first page to get the  number of pages to scrape, then I loop over each page and parse the HTML. The key pieces of info are put into a dictionary then added to a list (which is easier to write to csv via pandas since it's basically a dataframe already - a list of dicts)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import re
import concurrent.futures

def scrape_year(year):

    headers =   {
        'accept':'*/*',
        'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36',
        }

    url = f'https://aviation-safety.net/wikibase/dblist.php?Year={year}&sorteer=datekey&page=1'
    req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,'html.parser')

    page_container = soup.find('div',{'class':'pagenumbers'})
    pages = max([int(page['href'].split('=')[-1]) for page in  page_container.find_all('a')])

    info = []
    for page in range(1,pages+1):

        new_url = f'https://aviation-safety.net/wikibase/dblist.php?Year={year}&sorteer=datekey&page={page}'
        print(new_url)

        data = requests.get(new_url,headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text,'html.parser')


        table = soup.find('table',{'class':'hp'})


        regex = re.compile('list.*')
        for index,row in enumerate(table.find_all('tr',{'class':regex})):
            if index == 0:
                continue

            acc_link = 'https://aviation-safety.net/'+row.find('a')['href']
            try:
                acc_date = datetime.strptime(row.find('a').text.strip(),'%d-%b-%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            except ValueError:
                try:
                    acc_date = datetime.strptime("01"+row.find('a').text.strip(),'%d-%b-%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                except ValueError:
                    try:
                        acc_date = datetime.strptime("01-01"+row.find('a').text.strip(),'%d-%b-%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                    except ValueError:
                        continue

            acc_type = row.find_all('td')[1].text
            acc_reg = row.find_all('td')[2].text
            acc_operator = row.find_all('td')[3].text
            acc_fat = row.find_all('td')[4].text
            acc_location = row.find_all('td')[5].text
            acc_dmg = row.find_all('td')[7].text

            item = {
                'acc_link' : acc_link,
                'acc_date': acc_date,
                'acc_type': acc_type,
                'acc_reg': acc_reg,
                'acc_operator' :acc_operator,
                'acc_fat':acc_fat,
                'acc_location':acc_location,
                'acc_dmg':acc_dmg
                }

            info.append(item)

    df= pd.DataFrame(info)
    df.to_csv(f'{year}_aviation-safety.csv',index=False)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    START = 1916
    STOP = 2022

    years = [year for year in range(START,STOP+1)]

    print(f'Scraping {len(years)} years of data')

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=60) as executor:
            final_list = executor.map(scrape_year,years)
```

Comment: This is very detailed.  Admittedly I need to study it a little.  Bushcat69, I am thankful indeed.   The acc_link could provide further details, can the capture of these details be introduced in the code

Comment: Dear Bushcat69, looking [ https://aviation-safety.net/wikibase/dblist.php?Year=1916&sorteer=datekey&page=2 ] the third record at the bottom of the page is missing.  Could this be because of the date is missing the day? can this be captured?

Comment: I've edited the code to capture the incidents with missing date information and assumed the 1st of the month. Unfortunately adding the details by going into each incident will take a significant amount of time, as you'd need to make thousands of additional requests. Perhaps you can make this a new project

Comment: Dear Bushcat69, great coding I must say.  Could you explain how these work:  1) headers =   { 'accept':'*/*',    2) pages = max([int(page['href'].split('=')[-1]).    3) with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=60) as executor:
            final_list = executor.map(scrape_year,years)

Comment: 1) I just use a default looking header to cover my tracks in case they block requests that don't have "accept" and "user-agent" which sometimes happens

Comment: 2) Sorry, this is overly complicated but what it does is get the maximum number of pages using "list comprehension", I get all the links at the bottom of the page ('a' tags) and the get the [href] for each, but split it on "=" making each a list, then get the last one ([-1]) and turn the text into an integer so I can get the max of all the integers ie the last page number  3) this is a context manager that starts 60 concurrent threads which process one year simultaneously, I feed the "scape _year" function a list (the years) and it processes them concurrently

Comment: Many many thanks!

Comment: It just occurred to me the only the current year (i.e. 2022) is left out of from the records.  for some reason STOP = 2022 is not possible

Comment: Because of how python indexes STOP = 2022 will actually stop at 2021, just change it to 2023 and it will include 2022

Comment: Dear bushcat69, respecting international languages the correct python code to use is --->df.to_csv('AircraftListing.csv',encoding='utf-8-sig',index=False).  There is still an issue with the code, the years before 1912 and the year after 2021 are not captured.

Answer (score 1):

#### What happens?

First of all, always look into the soup - therein lies the truth.

You are missing the headers in the request of the while loop, that causes an `403` error and the table is not select correct.

#### How to achieve?

Set the headers for your request in the while loop correct:

```
html = requests.get(url , headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36'})
```

Select your rows more specific - Note there is no `tbody` in the html:

```
        # Go throught table = tbody and extract the data under the 'td' tag
        for row in soup.select('table tr.list'):
```

Also check the selectors for the pagination:

```
# If more than one page then iterate through all of them        
if soup.select_one('div.pagenumbers span.current + a'):
    url = 'https://aviation-safety.net/wikibase/dblist.php'+soup.select_one('div.pagenumbers span.current + a')['href']
else:
    break
```

#### Example

```
import requests, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request

url = 'https://aviation-safety.net/wikibase/dblist.php?Year=1916&sorteer=datekey&page=1'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36'}

with open('1916_aviation-safety.csv', "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["acc. date", "Type", "Registration","operator", "fat", "Location", " ", "dmg", " ", " "])

    while True:
        print(url)
        html = requests.get(url , headers = headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

        # Go throught table = tbody and extract the data under the 'td' tag
        for row in soup.select('table tr.list'):
            writer.writerow([c.text if c.text else '' for c in row.select('td')])
            print(row)

        # If more than one page then iterate through all of them        
        if soup.select_one('div.pagenumbers span.current + a'):
            url = 'https://aviation-safety.net/wikibase/dblist.php'+soup.select_one('div.pagenumbers span.current + a')['href']
        else:
            break
```

#### Just in case

Alternative solution with `pandas.read_html()` that iterates over all years:

```
import requests,time,random
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://aviation-safety.net/wikibase/'
req = requests.get(url , headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')


data = []

for url in ['https://aviation-safety.net/'+a['href'] for a in soup.select('a[href*="/wikibase/dblist.php"]')]:
    while True:

        html = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

        data.append(pd.read_html(soup.prettify())[0])

        # If more than one page then iterate through all of them        
        if soup.select_one('div.pagenumbers span.current + a'):
            url = 'https://aviation-safety.net/wikibase/dblist.php'+soup.select_one('div.pagenumbers span.current + a')['href']
        else:
            break
        time.sleep(random.random())

df = pd.concat(data)
df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')].to_csv('aviation-safety.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: HedgeHog, thank you for pointed out tbody isn't there.  The page iteration code from the " if " statement is not iterating through but only get stuck on the first page.

Comment: Dear HedgeHog, I have a question about " headers ", can the first one be omitted in the code? I am running the code since about 15min and looking forward to seeing the output file " aviation-safety.csv "

Comment: the second one, forgotten to replace by variable - just edited.

Comment: Dear HedgeHog, this works like a Swiss Watch! Many thanks!!!

Comment: Dear HedgeHog, I may have spoken a bit too soon the other day.  I would like to point out two things: 1) in the dataset both French and German characters like à ä è ü exist but the code uses √° instead. 2)Sometimes the code fails to establish a new connection: [Errno 60] Operation timed out.  Is there a work around these two points.  Many thanks

Comment: I thought this below would solve the issue, but does NOT        df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')].to_csv('aviation-safety.csv', encoding='utf-8' , index=False)      .  What's the solution ?

Comment: Super that you could solve this point for yourself, gladly I take over this addition, although this does not occur with me, often it also depends on system specifics. As for the second point, it is only a script not a complete approach, so you can definitely expand it and write away the broken connections and call again later, because the other side must also play along.

Comment: Oh, does not work? May try to set `encoding='utf-8'` for requests or read_html

Comment: encoding='utf-8' does not work.  would encoding='utf-16' be the answer?  Foreign language characters work better with UTF16 encoding, so giving it a go and will revert shortly